# Alguna forma de regresar un lista usando clases en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Estoy haciendo un pequeño ejemplo con clases en Python pero quiero que me imprima una lista de elementos así que utilice `__str__` pero me marco el error de no era un tipo `string` aquí esta mi código:

```
class intSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = []
    def insert(self, e):
        if e not in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(e)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.vals

s = intSet()
s.insert(1)
s.insert(4)
s.insert(6)
print(s)
```

¿Existe alguna función la cual regrese una lista?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Retornar una lista se hace tan sencillo como lo estás haciendo, el único problema es que [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) es un método muy especial y sirve para "customizar" el objeto creado. Particularmente [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) define la forma en que va a funcionar un `str()` común sobre el objeto. Como `str()` está obligada a retornar un cadena y en tu ejemplo el `print(s)` invoca implícitamente a `str()`, lo que deberías hacer es:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.vals)
```

O eventualmente puedes configurar el método [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__), que es más abarcativo ya que se usa en caso de no tener definido [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__).

```
def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.vals)
```

Agrego una aclaración importante, tanto [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) como [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) son funciones que sirven para generar una representación digamos que "gráfica" tipo cadena del objeto, en tu ejemplo elegimos la forma más sencilla de representar al objeto: un simple `str` de una lista, pero la representación es a gusto del autor o según las complejidades del objeto, lo importante es que el retorno sea siempre una cadena.

Comment: Muchas gracias, de las dos maneras ha funcionado.